Positive-Negative Voltage PWM Driver Design
I've noticed the following positive-negative PWM driver circuit in the OpenEVSE project. This circuit converts 5V CMOS-level PWM signal input (marked "PWM_IN") into a signal that swings between +12V and -12V (marked "PILOT_OUT"). Additionally, there's an analog readout input of the output voltage (marked "PILOT_ADC_READ"), to sense a connected load.
PWM frequency is 1kHz, and max output current is around 10mA.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Given that this project has been active for many years now, and this hardware had several revisions, I'm wondering about the choice of an op-amp and voltage divider as a driver, rather than a simple MOSFET push-pull driver using a single complementary MOSFET pair IC with appropriate voltage rating (e.g. BSL308C), meaning, a circuit like this:

simulate this circuit
What am I missing? What are the advantages of the op-amp and voltage divider circuit over the MOSFET push-pull driver?

The mosfet version will not work with 0-5V on input. It needs full swing -12+12V on input to control the Fets.
In op-amp version I would choose a rail-to-rail opamp, otherwise you will not get a full -12+12V swing on output because of emitter followers in
op-amp output.
Btw, are you sure about 12ohm resistor? It will clamp the output.

Thanks for your reply. Not sure how that resistor ended up with the 12ohm value, I fixed the schematics.
Of course, you're right about the required input range for the FETs circuit, I haven't analyzed this circuit through.
As for the op-amp not being rail-to-rail, this is the design in the project I referenced, I assume it isn't required to achieve full swing - as I mentioned, this is an old and tested project.
